# Office 2010: Customizing keyboard shortcuts for advanced find options

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, find, microsoft-office-2010, advanced-format

I repeatedly do the following to find text with a certain color in Word 2010:

```
Navigation > Advanced find > More > Find "Format" > Font > Font color > Custom
```

and then type the color that I want to find (e.g.: 0/112/192).  I am looking to save this choice of color so it can be selected using a keyboard shortcut or a command in the Quick Access Toolbar.

I know of customizing shortcuts using: `Options > Customize Ribbon`, but I don't know where to find the 'find advanced font color format' option.

Here is a screenshot of the option needed:

[image: Here is a screenshot of the option needed:]